# Laravel API routes - Same path, multiple methods

Tags: laravel, api, methods, routes

I want to make manually, some endpoints for a customer model.

I have these routes :

```
Route::get('customer/', 'CustomerRestController@all')->name('api_customer_all');
Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerRestController@get')->name('api_customer_get');
Route::post('customer/', 'CustomerRestController@addOrUpdate')->name('api_customer_post');
Route::delete('customer/{id}', 'CustomerRestController@delete')->name('api_customer_delete');
```

If I call the post route with postman, the GET response is return !

[image]
[image]

Do you know why please ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have different verbs for the same route, but you need to use the corresponding method in your request. Show how you're calling your API via Postman. Also, what does your `addOrUpdate` method contain? It might be calling a redirect.

Comment: Hi @TimLewis, thanks for your answer ! I just edited the post to show you the addOrUpdate method and the postman call .. As you can see, it return the get method and not the empty array in the addOrUpdate method